# Rabbitmq for messanger app

Tags: android, ios, rabbitmq

I am a student and want to develop messanger app as my high school project.I am developing a messaging app where one person can have 10 million followers.If user sends a message(example alert:world is in danger),It will be instantly recieved by all followers.Moreover I am considering rabbitmq as my messaging platform where each follower will be considered as consumer.Can anybody tell me how can I start to implement this Or there is another platform availble where I acan easily implement this application?

Answer (score 0):

You should really take a look at the RabbitMQ developer docs. Especially the Java part.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html#java-dev